# populate array with multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to use jQuery to populate an array with values from input fields with a class of 'seourl'...

```
<input id="title" class="seourl" name="title" type="text" value="???">
<input id="subtitle" class="seourl" name="title" type="text" value="???">
<input id="subtitle2" class="seourl" name="title" type="text" value="???">

<a id="getFriendlyUrl" href="">get url friendly</a>
```

How do i populate the array with input fields of class 'seourl'?

```
$("#getFriendlyUrl").click(function() {

    var arr_str = new Array();

    ?????? POPULATE ARRAY with input fields of class 'seourl', how ??????????????

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#getFriendlyUrl").click(function() {

    var arr_str = $('.seourl').map(function() {
                                       return this.value;
                                   }).toArray();
});
```

You can use jQuery to get the `.value` if you want.

```
return $(this).val();
```

Either way, you'll end up with an Array of the values.

Comment: `.toArray()`? Wouldn't the return value of `.map` be an array already?

Comment: I like your answer better. :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: No, that would be either the native `Array.prototype.map`, or `$.map`. This one returns a jQuery object. :-)

Comment: Oh yes my bad, I was thinking about `$.map`. +1 `=]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.seourl').each(function(ele){
    arr_str.push($(ele).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#getFriendlyUrl").click(function() {
    var arr_str = new Array();

    $('.seourl').each(function() {

        arr_str.push( $(this).val() );
    })'

});
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<input id="title" class="seourl" name="title" type="text" value="???">
<input id="subtitle" class="seourl" name="title" type="text" value="???">
<input id="subtitle2" class="seourl" name="title" type="text" value="???">

<a id="getFriendlyUrl" href="">get url friendly</a>​
```

JS w/jquery:

```
$("#getFriendlyUrl").click(function() {

    var arr_str = new Array();

    $(".seourl").each(function(index, el) {
     arr_str[index] = $(el).val();   
    });
    alert(arr_str[0] + arr_str[1] + arr_str[2]);

});​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/NmS7Y/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#getFriendlyUrl").click(function() {

    var arr_str = new Array();
    $('.seourl').each(function() {
        arr_str.push($(this).attr('value'));

    });
    alert(arr_str);
});
```